# file replication using asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have two servers and I need to replicate file. If I upload a file to server 1 file should get replicated to server 2 automatically and similarly if I delete the file then file should get deleted from other server. I got an idea that I can use WCF but how I don't know.

How can I do it?

Comment: There is No Need of Wcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this can be done in so many ways all raging from DropBox ( [Developers reference](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) ) to DFS Replication in Windows Server ( [DFS Sync blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2013/07/31/dfs-replication-in-windows-server-2012-r2-revenge-of-the-sync.aspx) ). You can ofcourse also use WCF or any of the other ways that exist to upload files to a server including [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) and other lightweight frameworks (Owin, Kayak, Firefly..) but if you would choose that path you will need to write upload, remove, sync code for each action that your system need to handle and while do-able it does not seem like the most effective ways, but perhaps you have other needs that were not explained in your original post?

Search some on the topics, try to implement something and if you get stuck feel free to return to Stackoverflow with your code and questions.